# Ruby: how to view the definition of Date.leap?

Tags: ruby

I have tried the following:

```
method = Date.method(:leap?)

puts method

location=method.source_location

puts location
```

Here is the output: # Method: Date.leap?

Comment: I also read this but no luck : http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2013/2/13/view-source-ruby-methods

Comment: What is your objective? To find whether a date is leap or not?

Comment: My objective is to view the source code / definition of the Date.Leap? method

Comment: did you consider using pry for that? http://railscasts.com/episodes/280-pry-with-rails

Comment: Cant we get this without using 'pry'? BTW,how do I get the 'pry' ?   I tried : gem install pry  and here is the error :C:\Ruby193\bin>gem install pry
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'pry' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    SocketError: getaddrinfo: No such host is known.  (http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

Comment: looks like a SSL error. I also noticed you are using windows. I am not acquainted to windows programming environment, so I may not be of much help here. However you can still try this: `gem install pry --source http://rubygems.org`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Date::leap?` is not written in Ruby, it's written in C (at least on the YARV implementation of Ruby).

`Method#source_location` returns the location in Ruby source code, but `Date::leap?` doesn't *have* any Ruby source code, therefore it returns `nil`.

You will have to dig deep into the C source of YARV, if you want to find what you are looking for.

First, you'l notice on [lines 9314-9315 of `ext/date/date_core.c`](https://GitHub.Com/Ruby/Ruby/blob/trunk/ext/date/date_core.c#L9314-9315) that `leap?` is implemented by the function `date_s_gregorian_leap_p`:

```
rb_define_singleton_method(cDate, "leap?", 
                           date_s_gregorian_leap_p, 1);
```

The definition of `date_s_gregorian_leap_p` is on [lines 2918-2926 of `ext/date/date_core.c`](https://GitHub.Com/Ruby/Ruby/blob/trunk/ext/date/date_core.c#L2918-2926):

```
static VALUE
date_s_gregorian_leap_p(VALUE klass, VALUE y)
{
    VALUE nth;
    int ry;

    decode_year(y, -1, &nth, &ry);
    return f_boolcast(c_gregorian_leap_p(ry));
}
```

You'll notice that it simply calls `c_gregorian_leap_p`, which is defined on [lines 682-686 of `ext/date/date_core.c`](https://GitHub.Com/Ruby/Ruby/blob/trunk/ext/date/date_core.c#L682-686):

```
inline static int
c_gregorian_leap_p(int y)
{
    return (MOD(y, 4) == 0 && y % 100 != 0) || MOD(y, 400) == 0;
}
```

Last but not least, here are the definitions of [`MOD`](https://GitHub.Com/Ruby/Ruby/blob/trunk/ext/date/date_core.c#L150):

```
#define MOD(n,d) ((n)<0 ? NMOD((n),(d)) : (n)%(d))
```

and [`NMOD`](https://GitHub.Com/Ruby/Ruby/blob/trunk/ext/date/date_core.c#L148):

```
#define NMOD(x,y) ((y)-(-((x)+1)%(y))-1)
```

However, I personally find YARV to be the most unreadable of all Ruby implementations. I much prefer looking at the source code of [JRuby](https://GitHub.Com/jruby/) or [Rubinius](https://GitHub.Com/rubinius/).

For example, here's the same method in Rubinius. Well, actually, unlike YARV, Rubinius doesn't ship its own implementation of the standard library, instead it uses the gemified standard library from the [RubySL (Ruby Standard Library)](https://GitHub.Com/RubySL/) project.

As you can see on [line 730 of `lib/rubysl/date/date.rb` of the `rubysl-date` gem](https://GitHub.Com/RubySL/RubySL-Date/blob/2.0/lib/rubysl/date/date.rb#L730), `Date::leap?` is defined as an alias of `Date::gregorian_leap?`:

```
class << self; alias_method :leap?, :gregorian_leap? end
```

Which is defined directly above in [line 728 of `lib/rubysl/date/date.rb` of the `rubysl-date` gem](https://GitHub.Com/RubySL/RubySL-Date/blob/2.0/lib/rubysl/date/date.rb#L728):

```
def self.gregorian_leap? (y) y % 4 == 0 && y % 100 != 0 || y % 400 == 0 end
```

Comment: I read a lot of documents for answering this question and in turn even learned a lot of new things. But I never took the approach you did. Thanks for your answer. +1

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag,  Thanks for providing insight into this. While I understood why source_Location  is returning nil & also how the C program is being written, I am sure I will get a better understanding by debugging the C-code. Thanks so much!